# Issue with Rank 4 and feed_dict (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my placeholder:

```
X = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(1, 1, 1, 5), name="data")
```

here is the feed_dict:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],feed_dict= {X: [ [1], [1], 
np.array([[nest[epoch], tree[epoch], 
veg[epoch], longitude[epoch], lat[epoch]]]), [1]] , Y: 
occupancy[epoch]})
```

However it is throwing this error, even when move position of the np.array in the feed, or the 5 within the shape of the placeholder:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5) into shape 
(1)
```

I think the issue lies in not knowing how to make the np.array itself be 4D (which is required for convolution). 
Bit of background: Trying to make convolutional network from raw data rather than an image. Any help would be appreciated, sorry if I didn't make this clear,  thanks :)

Comment: your input to X should be of this form: [[[[a, b, c, d, e]]]] for size (1,1,1,5). Why cant you keep the placeholder as (5)?

Comment: ah that worked thank you very much. Was unaware that 4 pairs of brackets were required!